# I Installed XAMPP 7.4.4 on my windows 10 .While openign the localhst the the UI look completely broken and phpmyadmin is not loading at all

Tags: xampp, xampp-vm

I installed successfully XAMPP version 7.4.4 on my windows 10. I started bith apache and Mysql from XAMPP control panel. But while opening localhost ,the home page is nt loading properly. and phpmyadmin page keep on loading and nothing appears even after loading for a long time.

Before this I installed ampps .Same UI issue I faced there also. Is there any thing blocking in my system or what could be the issue?
If I upload any website also those ui also coming broken. And taking lot of time and keep on loading.

My Xampp control panel:

[image]

PHPMyAdmin:

[image]

Homepage coming broken:

[image]